# Python / Numpy: How can I avoid these for-loops?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to refactor these two functions to get rid of the `for`-loops. Any ideas how this can be done using python / numpy?

```
def hessian(self, theta, X):
    matrix = np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
    for x in X:
        g = self.gFunc(theta, x)
        outer = np.outer(x, x)
        matrix = matrix + g * (1.0 - g) * outer
    return -matrix

def gradient(self, theta, X, Y):
    gradient = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    for x, y in zip(X, Y):
        g = self.gFunc(theta, x)
        gradient = gradient + (y - g) * x
    return gradient
def gFunc(self, theta, x):
    dot = np.dot(theta, x)
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-dot))
```

Comment: If that is not too much code, can you share some input example data and gfunc function ? It would allow to test code

Comment: @azro I added `gFunc`

Comment: @azro `x` is a 3-length array

Comment: `(y - g) *x` is a `3x1`-array. At least it should be?

Comment: @azro `x` is NOT an int. It is a 3x1 array. `X` is an array of 3x1 arrays

Comment: Couldn't guess ^^

Answer (score 0):

More or less, you can use the same operator for unitary operation and use them for numpy arrays, for addition, muliplication, ...

```
def gradient2(self, theta, X: np.ndarray, Y: np.ndarray):
    return np.multiply(Y - self.gFunc(theta, X), X).sum(axis=0)
```

---

For `hessian`, because of the `np.outer` I don't see how it could be simplified